# What's the difference between 創造的{そうぞうてき} and 創造性{そうぞうせい}?

Tags: word-choice, suffixes

What's the difference between 創造的{そうぞうてき} and 創造性{そうぞうせい}?  I know they both relate to creativity, but I am not sure what the exact difference between them is.

Do the 的{てき} and 性{せい} endings signify anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some cases that when 的 attaches to a noun, it becomes a na-adjective as 創造的な (creative), 詩的な (poetic). And there are some cases that な may be omitted as 詩的表現 (poetic expression), 歴史的事件 (historical happening).

There are some cases that when 性 attaches to a noun as 創造性 (creativity), 安全性 (safety), 機動性 (mobility), it means "property, nature, and character of the noun" and it remains a noun.